# Is there a kind of random walk process for wich the reciprocal of the variance is a sum of reciprocals of variances of compound processes?

Tags: correlation, variance, random-walk

**Context:** The variance of a sum of independent random walks is a sum of their variances: $\sigma^2 = \sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2$. In case of a dependent random walks with bivariate normal distribution it will be $\sigma^2 = \sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2 + 2 \rho \sigma_1 \sigma_2$.

**Question:** Is there any known class of dependent random walk processes for which the reciprocal of variance is a sum of reciprocals of variances of each random walk process: $1/\sigma^2 = 1/\sigma_1^2 + 1/\sigma_2^2$ ? Can one infer any useful statistical information about such processes, given the relation holds true?

**Remark:** The relation $1/\sigma_{total} = 1/\sigma_{diffusion-controlled-process} + 1/\sigma_{advection-controlled-process}$ follows from the coupling theory of eddy dispersion [1] (formula 2.10-8): the total dispersion of a chromatographic peak is due to diffusional-based and advectional-base mechanisms. This relation describes a corpus of the experimental data quite well, however Giddings derived the theory with a lot of assumptions and to me it seems more like an empirical correlation, which lacks rigorous statistical reasoning. I am trying to reverse engineer it and find out what kind of a relationship between two processes may lead to this peculiar rule for the sum of the variances.

[1] Giddings, J. C. (1965). Dynamics of Chromatography, Part 1: Principles and Theory. New York, NY, USA: Marcel Dekker.

Comment: It is difficult to see how the relation you quote for chromotographic peaks could be true: it would imply that somehow diffusion and advection together create *less* dispersion than either one separately.  Incidentally, the [harmonic mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean) of any positive numbers $x$ and $y$ is $2/(1/x+1/y)$.

Comment: Such an equation would suggest a very particular kind of (possibly quite strong, presumably nonlinear) negative dependence.

Comment: @whuber Indeed the harmonic mean does not fit here. Thank you for pointing that out. I will change the wording now.

Comment: @whuber I will try to address the rest of your concerns in several steps.
First: I am sorry for misleading you -- the subscript diffusion is not correct (I have changed it now). I did not mean diffusion per se, rather I meant a process, whose dynamics is controlled by diffusion. The derivation of this relationship by Giddings is quite lengthy and probably is not relevant for Cross Validated audience. If you are interested I might lay out the derivation of Giddings somewhere else and point you to it, so you can follow his reasoning.

Comment: @whuber Second: There has been an argument in the chromatographic community which started in the end of the fifites [1] between the theory which stated that the variances sum up and the one that yields (or rather assumes) the sum of reciprocals of variances. The experimental and simulation data of numerous authors including yours truly [2] corroborate the latter model. I suspect it actually stemmed from the attempt to describe the experimental data.
[1] http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v184/n4683/abs/184357a0.html
[2] http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ac200424p

Comment: @whuber I am not questioning the model, rather I am trying to reverse engineer: to go from the macroscopic behavior of the model to it's components and figure out what kind of elementary behavior of random walkers can lead to the expression $1/\sigma_{total} = 1/\sigma_{diffusion-controlled-process} + 1/\sigma_{advection-controlled-process}$.

Comment: @Glen_b Indeed there is a strong dependence between the processes. From http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v187/n4742/abs/1871023b0.html 
"Variances add, for certain independent processes which, by virtue of an elementary random event, contribute directly to the variance. Lateral diffusion is not such a process. The variance is caused by non-equilibrium established by the difference in downstream velocity from point to point. Lateral diffusion acts to reduce this variance as can be seen by the inverse relationship between variance or plate height and diffusion coefficient."

Comment: Thank you for your enlightening comments. As is indicated by calculations like those in Alecos Papdopulos' post, this relationship between the variances can get you only partway there: even assuming the total process is a linear combination of dependent processes, the coefficients are not identifiable. Additional information would be needed to estimate those coefficients and to check whether the combined process is approximated as a linear combination at all.

Answer (score 2):

From

$$1/\sigma^2 = 1/\sigma_1^2 + 1/\sigma_2^2$$
we get

$$\sigma^2 = \frac {\sigma_1^2\sigma_2^2}{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2}$$

Consider the process

$$Z = c_1X_1+c_2X_2$$
where $c_1, c_2$ are constants. If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent, we want to have

$$\text{Var}(Z) = \sigma^2  \Rightarrow c_1^2\sigma_1^2+c_2^2\sigma_2^2 = \frac {\sigma_1^2\sigma_2^2}{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2}$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac {1}{\sigma_2^2}c_1^2+\frac {1}{\sigma_1^2}c_2^2 = \frac {1}{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2}$$

There are many pairs of $\{c_1,c_2\}$ that satisfy this equation, so there are many linear combinations of the two independent random walks that can satisfy the initial equation.